# Mysql query to find jobs with dependencies completed

Tags: mysql, sql

I have modeled jobs and it's dependencies in sql tables:
jobs (id, detail, exit_code)
dependencies (job_id, dependenet_job_id)

Ex: if job 1 depends on 2 and 3, the tables will have the following:
jobs
1 "job1" NULL
2 "job2" NULL
3 "job3" NULL
4 "job4" NULL

dependencies
1 2
1 3

Now I need to find the jobs which can be run next. In above case 2,3 and 4 can be run as they don't have any dependencies. 1 can run only when 2 and 3 are completed successfully (exit code = 0).

The tables can have hundreds of jobs and multi level dependencies. I have query to get jobs without dependencies using left outer join. But having trouble with finding jobs whose dependencies have been completed successfully.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "nested" dependencies (i.e. job1 depends on job2 that depends on job3), you would need a recursive query, which MySQL doesn't support as is.

You can check this article about how to [reengineer your tables](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html) to handle recursion.

Another thing you can do is:

**whenever a job completes, its dependencies are removed or deactivated (you add a boolean column `active` to the dependency table)**.

This way, you can run a

```
SELECT jobs.* FROM jobs
    LEFT JOIN depends ON (jobs.id = depends.parent_id AND depends.active = TRUE)
    WHERE depends.child_id IS NULL
          AND jobs.started = FALSE;
```

This will return all jobs that have not started, but that have no active dependencies.

Once you select a job, you run

```
UPDATE jobs SET started=TRUE WHERE id = @JOB_ID;
```

and when it finishes,

```
UPDATE jobs SET exitcode=@EXIT_CODE WHERE id = @JOB_ID;
UPDATE dependencies SET active = FALSE WHERE child_id = @JOB_ID;
-- or
DELETE FROM dependencies WHERE child_id = @JOB_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The form of the query is "select jobs where there is no dependent job that hasn't completed"

```
Select
  *
from
  jobs j
where
  not exists (
    select
      'x'
    from
      dependencies d
        inner join
      jobs j2
        on d.dependent_job_id = j2.id
    where
      j.id = d.job_id and (
        j2.exit_code is null or -- job hasn't completed successfully
        j2.exit_code != 0
      )
  );
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0582b/1)</kbd>**